# Django Tastypie: permissions for ManyToManyFields

Tags: python, django, web-services, many-to-many, tastypie

It's possible give delete permissions only for a m2m field of my model?
Let's think in:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    favourited_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

If i write this ModelResource:

```
class SiteResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Site.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'Site'
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get', 'delete']
```

I'm giving delete permissions for the whole model, but i only want to be able to delete entries from "favourited_by" field. There's some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a delete on that endpoint, by definition, should delete the whole object.

But if you are looking for a custom behaviour, then you could override `obj_delete` with something like:

```
def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    # Get the object and raise NotFound if couldn't find
    try:
        bundle.obj = self.obj_get(bundle=bundle, **kwargs)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound("A model instance matching the provided arguments could not be found.")

    #Here you should do any kind of validation before deleting

    # And then remove using the parameter you passed (for example user_id)
    bundle.obj.favourited_by.remove(User.objects.get(id=bundle.data['user_id']))  #pass in the user_id
    return
```